# are disk controllers necessary?

Tags: sata

I think the question is straight forward.
I just bought a hard drive (Western Digital HC320 Ultrastar 8TB DataCenter)
and in the official page under compatibility, I noticed so many devices
after a bit of research, I discovered they were "Disk controllers"
as my hard drive is not working so far with a SATA iii to USB adapater alongside a 12V 1A power supply
when I plug it to my computer (HP 250 g4).
so I want to know if the "disk con gtroller" is necessary and this wont work without it.
and if yes, then in what cases a hard drive needs a disk controller, and in what cases it doesnt.
thank you.

Comment: Your power supply probably doesn't provide enough power.

Comment: The model of USB docking station the OP is using might help: we can look at the chipset and the power supplied. I don't know what the Laptop can supply via USB, but the drive listed looks to peak at about 500mA on 12 v and 200mV on 5v if I interpret it correctly. (https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/data-center-drives/ultrastar-dc-hc300-series/product-manual-ultrastar-dc-hc320-sata-oem-spec.pdf) section 6.3

Comment: Thank you and OP stands for? I checked that link but on the drive i see 5VDC0.7A and 12VDC0.9A but the amper doesnt really matter if it's high, the disk will only take what it needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disk *always* needs a disk controller; in most end-user scenarios you simply don't see it, unless you are paying attention.

Normally, a SATA disk controller is integrated in every motherboard (either server-class or end-user ones). A "SATA to USB adapter" is a device which actually includes a mini disk controller in order to make the PC and the disk talk using USB.

Other disk types (SCSI, SAS) need different controllers, and also even for SATA disks there are controllers which offer additional capabilities (like hardware RAID); in all of these cases, the controller is an actual physical card that you plug in the computer.

That said, not every disk works with every controller; that's why you have a hardware compatibility list.